# How to solve T(n) = T(n-2) + T(2) + n with recursion tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

I want to find the complexity of an algorithm that involves the recurrence:

T(n) = T(n-2) + T(2) + n

T(n) is the time it takes to solve a problem of size n. I want to use recursion tree but my problem is T(2), can we consider T(2) will be dominated by T(n-2).

Answer (score 2):

Say you start with

*T(n) = T(n - 2) + T(2) + n*.

Then

*T(n) =*

*T(n - 2) + T(2) + n =*

*T(n - 4) + 2T(2) + n + (n - 2) =*

*T(n - 6) + 3T(2) + n + (n - 2) + (n - 4) =*

*...*

*T(k) + Θ(n) T(2) + ∑<sub>i = n, n - 2, ..., k</sub>[i]*

where *k* is some constant.

In the last expression,

*T(2)* is a constant, so *Θ(n) T(2) = Θ(n)*. Also

*∑<sub>i = n, n - 2, ..., k</sub>[i] = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*, since it's an arithmetic series.

Altogether, *T(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*.